# Should I use the at symbol (@) in my php code

Tags: php, performance

I have recently learned how to use the @ symbol in my php code and I have learned to love it. However I have also been told that @ is not efficient performance wise. Is the elegance it provides enough to excuse the performance hit it might or might not create.

One common usage which I implement is in an if statement when trying to access an array.

```
if( $value = @$array['key'] )
// value exists and we can access it
```

Because it returns null instead of displaying an error it is a useful tool in situations as this one.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is error suppressing bad practice?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/219788/is-error-suppressing-bad-practice)

Comment: Currently it has met all my needs, I am afraid of the potential damage this technique could cause as I scale my application

Comment: When you say *performance*, are you only talking about CPU cycles, or you considering the extra time spent debugging because helpful warning messages are suppressed?

Comment: Learning what `@` does and using it together in conjunction with term performance is ridiculous. You "love" the error **suppression** but you are worried about performance. This raises two questions - 1) do you have performance issues and 2) why do you choose to suppress errors over **not having errors**. You see, code that contains errors and programmer deliberately suppresses them indicates that the programmer doesn't really know enough at this point. But that programmer is worried about performance - shouldn't the programmer ensure there are no errors first?

Answer (score 3):

Suppressing errors in this way is useful, but not for your example because there are more traditional ways to check for those potential errors.

I use it sometimes, but normally for IO operations.  For example.

```
$sample = 'sample.txt';

if (!file_exists($sample)) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException($sample);
}

if (!$fp = @fopen('sample.txt', 'r')) {
    throw new IOException($sample, error_get_last()['message']);
}
```

The exceptions in this are classes I would have created.   The goal is to open a file for reading, first I need to check the file exists, thats easy, if it doesn't I can throw a relevant error.

Next is to open the file.  Well this is a nothing or all operation and there could be a multitude of reasons why it won't work (permissions for example).

I want to handle the the problem if there is one (in this case by catching an exception) so I suppress the error (because I don't want users to see it), but I do want to know what happened, so I catch the exception, log the message somewhere and redirect the user somewhere else.

I use `@` because I don't know what the error might be and because depending on the PHP configuration it will always trigger an error regardless of what you do with the return value.

Don't use it for something like getting an array value by index, because there are very few types of problems with this and they can all be checked for before starting the operation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that it affects perfomance is that it still triggers all the error handling mechanisms within PHP even though the generation of error mesages is suppressed. The same problem arises if error_reporting() and error_logging() are disabled.

It does provide a quick fix solution, however the scenario you describe can also be acheived by:

```
$value = isset($array['key']) ? $array['key'] : null;
```

without triggering an error.